# TCP Client dropps large Packets

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp

I have a networking application using TcpClient in C#. In testing I send a lot of very big messages (e.g. 1000 50kB messages) over a loopback connection. This works fine most of the time, but sometimes the listening client can only receive the first few packets and then just keeps listening for more but they never come. As I said, this only happens in some cases, even though the packets are always generated using the same seed.

So there seems to be some other source of randomness determining if the test succeeds. I thought that might be because the Tcp Stream only keeps a certain max bytes after which all of them are dropped, so if the connection cannot keep consuming them fast enough the stream just gets clogged. I am still pretty new to all this stuff so this is just a shot in the dark, but maybe you know if there is some limit like that.

It could obviously also be some deadlock in my code, but after extensive debugging I have not been able to find anything like this. Funnily enough, when using Tracepoints and other debug tools that slow down the sending client enough, I have not been able to reproduce this bug, which could indicate a performance difference between sender and receiver as Issue??

Here is some simplified code of how the client reads from the `NetworkStream`:

```
byte[] prefixBuffer = new byte[4];
byte[] messageBuffer; //This is done without array pool for simplification

int writeIndex = 0; // Describes where the next byte will be written to



while(true){
    // Read until prefix buffer is full
    while(writeIndex < prefixBuffer.Length){
        writeIndex += stream.read(prefixBuffer, writeIndex, 4 - writeIndex);
    }
    
    writeIndex = 0;
    prefixBuffer = new byte[BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(prefixBuffer)]; // Renting from ArrayPool is skipped here for simplicity
    
    // Read until message buffer is full
    while(writeIndex < prefixBuffer.Length){ // Since this buffer is not rented we can use its size directly
        writeIndex += stream.read(messageBuffer, writeIndex, messageBuffer.Length - writeIndex);
    }
    

    // Handle message here
    

    writeIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: When you paused the program in  the debugger, while it was stuck, was it stuck in stream.Read?

Comment: @user253751 Yeah, it was. Should I edit that into the question?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Hm. But it waits until all 4 bytes have been read, atleast that was that I tried to do. It will always fill up the buffer, whether it is the 4 byte prefix or the message. Also sorry if it is rough, I had to shrink a lot of code into some postable form.

Comment: Also `BitConverter.ToInt32` will interpret the received bytes differently depending on the computer architecture.

Comment: @KlausGütter I did not think of that! Thank you very much, you saved me a lot of debugging time!

Comment: "But it waits until all 4 bytes have been read" - imagine the first Read returning 2 bytes and the second Read 4 bytes. You will overflow the buffer in this case.

Comment: What if nextBuffer is 10 long and 6 bytes are available for reading, 4 bytes for the length of the subsequent data and then 2 bytes of that data?

Comment: @KlausGütter That  is an artifact of me compacting the code, sorry. In my actual code, it only reads `nextBuffer.Length - index`. That should be safe, right? sorry, I am a bit of a rookie

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Yeah, the code works under the assumption that since the message buffer size is set by the sender the sender will always send a message of the length of the buffer and only after that a new prefix. So the buffer will either have the length of the prefix and read until the prefix is received, or the length of the message and read the whole message. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @JakobTinhofer: That's not how TCP works, it's a just a stream of data, there are no messages at the TCP level.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Yes I know. Thats why I use length prefixes as framing and always read until my buffers are filled.

Comment: It's possible I don't understand the code then.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Yeah sorry for the unreadable code. This is what it is supposed to do: allocate 4 byte buffer -> read up to 4 bytes -> add amount of read bytes to write index -> read up to `4 - index` bytes -> repeat until buffer full -> get package length -> do the same thing but with package length instead of 4 bytes -> then start all over read a new size prefix. I will try and edit the code to make that more clear.

Comment: `ArrayPool.Rent(n)` allocates an array with **at least** n bytes in it. There's no guarantee it's exactly n bytes.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk yes, that is why I always use a length saved in a different variable.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I updated the code, I hope it is more readable now.